# node, async programming, callback hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

i'm trying to understand callbacks and async programming, but I'm having a bit of trouble.

here's some pseudocode :

```
var lines = [];
var arrayOfFeedUrls = [url1,url2,...];

function scrape(url){
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.pipe(new FeedParser([options]))
        .on('readable', function () {
            var stream = this, item;
            while (item=stream.read()) {
                line = item.title;
                lines.push(line);
            }
        });
    });
});

for (i in arrayOfFeedUrls){
    scrape(arrayOfFeedUrls[i];
}
console.log(lines.length);
```

It obviously returns 0, as the scrape function is executed asynchronously. I understand that much, but I've tried many intricated ways and can't figure out how to write it properly. Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated. I've read (and I'm still reading) a lot of tutorials and examples, but I think the only way for me to get it is to write some code myself. If I solve this I'll post the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async#map

Comment: Look into Promises. I think they are the most elegant way of avoiding callback hell.

Comment: although async libraries will solve this issue, it doesn't explain how it should be solved.

Comment: Promises are fancy, but just naming and un-nesting your callbacks will drastically reduce clutter and confusion; just pass instead what would be closed, which helps document your procedures anyway. it's at least half as good as promises for a lot less effort and learning. in short, if the char "(" appears just after the chars "function", you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's how i've solved the problem, feel free to comment and tell me if it's right.

```
var lines = [];
var arrayOfFeedUrls = [url1,url2,...];

function scrape(array){
    var url = array.shift();
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.pipe(new FeedParser([options]))
        .on('readable', function () {
            var stream = this, item;
            while (item=stream.read()) {
                line = item.title;
                lines.push(line);
            }
        }).on('end', function () {
            if(array.length){
                scrapeFeeds(array);
            }
        });
    });
});

scrapeFeeds(array);
```

Thanks for all the answers, i'm looking more in depth to async as I've got more complicated stuff to do. Let me know what you think of my code, it's always useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could want to check [this article](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2013/07/12/teach-yourself-nodejs-in-10-steps) for an introduction in Node that might help you understand async programming in Node a little better.

As far as async programming goes, [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a very popular module in Node's userland which helps you write asynchronous code effortlessly. For instance (untested pseudo-code):

```
function scrape (done) {
  http.get(url, done);
}

function parse (res, done) {
  var lines = [];

  res.pipe(new FeedParser([options]))
        .on('readable', function () {
            var stream = this, item;
            while (item=stream.read()) {
                line = item.title;
                lines.push(line);
            }
        })
        .on('end', function () {
          done(null, lines);
        });
}

function done (err, lines) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  console.log(lines.length);
}

async.waterfall([scrape, parse], done);
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on if you want to scrape all urls in parallell or in series.

If you were to do it in series, you should think of it as this:

Start with the first url. Scrape. In the callback, scrape the next url. in the callback, scrape the next url.

This will give the notorious callback hell you are talking about, but that is the principle at least. That where librarires like async etc removes a lot of the headache.

Answer (score 1):

When programming async calls in this manner, functions and instructions that you want to chain onto the end, such as `console.log(lines.length);`, must also be callbacks. So for instance, try something like this:

```
var lines = [];
var arrayOfFeedUrls = [url1,url2,...];

function scrape(url){
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.pipe(new FeedParser([options]))
        .on('readable', function () {
            var stream = this, item;
            while (item=stream.read()) {
                line = item.title;
                lines.push(line);
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});

for (i in arrayOfFeedUrls){
    scrape(arrayOfFeedUrls[i];
}
function done () {
    if (lines.length == arrayOfFeedUrls.length) {
        console.log(lines.length);
    }
}
```

You may also want to look into [promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), an alternative programming style to callbacks, which aims to avoid callback hell.

Comment: I don't think lines.length will match urls.length, as there may be multiple lines per url.  (I think).  But I think you are on the right track - please see my answer and comment if you think that's an improvement (or not)

Answer (score 1):

Have to admit that I'm very new to node.js and struggling to grok the callback stuff.  In my limited experience, adding one more parameter to the callback function may be the trick.  The hard question is, which parameter?

In your example, if the function `scrape` had an extra boolean "lastOne", then it could call console.log(lines) itself.  Or, if it understood that a null url meant to stop.  *However, I don't think even this works*, as I'm not sure everything will get done in order.  If the 2nd URL takes forever, the last one may complete first, right???  (You could try it).  In other words, I still don't know which parameter to add.  Sorry...

What seems more reliable is to set a counter to urls.length, and for `scrape()` to decrement it each time.  When the counter reaches 0, it knows that the entire process is done and it should log (or do whatever) with the result.  I'm not 100% sure where to declare this counter.  Coming from Java I still have little idea what is a static global, what is an instance, whatever...

Now, a true-blue node.jser would pass a function to doWhatever as an extra parameter to `scrape()`, so that you can do something other than `console.log()`. :-)  But I'd settle for the check for zero.

to elaborate slightly, add a `callWhenDone` parameter to `scrape()`, and add (somewhere in all that nesting!!!)

```
if (--counter <= 0)
  callWhenDone (lines);
```

Comment: check my answer, there's a bit of yours inside :)